# JavaScript Generator: implement a ticket queue system

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, generator

I am trying to implement a ticket queue system, where by default it would have 3 different queues to holder tickets that are of severity 1, severity 2, and severity 3 respectively. And I have a method `getTicketAtHighestSeverity` in it that returns the oldest ticket in the highest severity queue, so it starts at the first queue and looks for the first item in the queue and moves onto the next queue if the current queue is empty and another method `getTicketBySeverity` to iterate through all the all queues return the ticket starting at the highest severity

Here is my implementation.

```js
class ticketQueues {
    constructor(numOfQueues = 3) {
        this.queues = Array.from({length: numOfQueues}).fill([])
    }

    addSev1(ticket) {
        this.queues[0].push(ticket)
    }

    addSev2(ticket) {
        this.queues[1].push(ticket)
    }

    addSev3(ticket) {
        this.queues[2].push(ticket)
    }

    *getTicketBySeverity() {
        for(const queue of this.queues) {
            for(const ticket of queue) {
                yield ticket
            }
        }

        return null
    }

    getTicketAtHighestSeverity() {
        for(const queue of this.queues) {
            for(const ticket of queue) {
                return ticket
            }
        }
        
        return null
    }

}
```

However it seems like `getTicketBySeverity` is not working properly.

```js
const queues = new ticketQueues()
queues.addSev1({timestamp: Date(), name: 't1'})
queues.addSev2({timestamp: Date(), name: 't2'})
queues.addSev3({timestamp: Date(), name: 't3'})

for(let i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(queues.getTicketBySeverity().next().value) //  this keeps returning the first item from the queue
}
```

Because it is not moving to the next ticket as it only returns the first ticket. The reason I chose Generator to implement this method is that I wanted to take advantage of the lazy evaluation model because the data set can be huge, I don't want to necessarily have to get all of the tickets all at once.

Can someone fix my implementation with `getTicketBySeverity`. And any suggestions about the naming here? I feel like the naming here i.e. `getTicketBySeverity` and `getTicketAtHighestSeverity` might not be the best choice. Also, feel free to comment on my usage of Generator here if you think this might not be a legit use case for that.

Comment: You keep creating new iterators by calling `queues.getTicketBySeverity()` again and again - each of them will start with the first ticket. The implementation of the method is perfectly fine (although the `return null` seems rather unnecessary).

Comment: @Bergi thanks that is indeed what is happening here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is

```
this.queues = Array.from({length: numOfQueues}).fill([])
```

`.fill` does not work well with non-primitives (usually), since each item in the new array will be a reference to the *same object*. You've only created a single array. The problem is the same as why the following doesn't work as one might expect:

```
const subarr = [];
arr.push(subarr);
arr.push(subarr);
```

since there's only one `subarr`.

Use a mapper function with `Array.from` to explicitly create a new array for each iteration:

```
this.queues = Array.from({length: numOfQueues}, () => []);
```

Also, to iterate over the iterator, use `for..of` - either that, or remove the found item from the array when it's found (otherwise, every time it's called, it'll return the same item).

You can control the number of tickets to remove at once with `for..of` by passing an argument to the generator and keeping track of the number of elements yielded:

```js
class ticketQueues {
    constructor(numOfQueues = 3) {
        this.queues = Array.from({length: numOfQueues}, () => []);
    }

    addSev1(ticket) {
        this.queues[0].push(ticket)
    }

    addSev2(ticket) {
        this.queues[1].push(ticket)
    }

    addSev3(ticket) {
        this.queues[2].push(ticket)
    }
    *getTicketsBySeverity(limit) {
        let count = 0;
        for(const queue of this.queues) {
            while (queue.length) {
                yield queue.shift();
                count++;
                if (count === limit) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}



const queues = new ticketQueues()
queues.addSev1({timestamp: Date(), name: 't1'})
queues.addSev1({timestamp: Date(), name: 't1-2'})
queues.addSev2({timestamp: Date(), name: 't2'})
queues.addSev3({timestamp: Date(), name: 't3'})

for (const ticket of queues.getTicketsBySeverity(3)) {
  console.log(ticket);
}
console.log(queues.queues);
```

Comment: I tried to print out this part `Array.from({length: numOfQueues}).fill([])` and it looks perfectly fine, i.e. `[[], [], []]` also yoru `for of` loop works with the generator function but it kinda defeats the purpose here. The reason I implemented it with generator is to avoid the run-to-completion behavior so I can control how many tickets I wanted to pull out of the queues. Is there a way to not loop over the way to the end the queue?

Comment: sorry actuall you are right ` Array.from({length: numOfQueues}).fill([])` does cause an issue here

Comment: If you want to control the number of tickets removed, pass an argument and keep track of the number of items removed so far so you can return when needed.

Comment: I see you updated the snippet. thanks for the suggestions! I posted a complete imlemention for code review here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254810/implementation-of-a-ticket-queue-system-in-javascript. could you take a look if you have time?